# Enable value not in the list to be shown - System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a column in a data grid view. I created a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` for it and set the data source to a list of values.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn1.DataSource = new List<string>{ "...", "..." };
```

Not all the value of the column is in the list. I want the user to be able to select the value in the list and update the value for these values not existing in the list.

However, the system keeps popping up the following error for these values not in the list when loading the data grid view.

> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Is it another data grid view control for this purpose? Or is it possible to suppress the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the following events:

- [`DataError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror?view=netframework-4.7.2): To prevent exception dialog while rendering the cell.
- [`CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2): To show value of the cells which doesn't exists in the combo box values.

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1");
    dt.Rows.Add("A");
    dt.Rows.Add("B");
    dt.Rows.Add("C");
    dt.Rows.Add("D");

    var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "C1";
    column.Name = "C1";
    column.DataSource = new List<string> { "A", "B" };

    dataGridView1.DataError += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (a.ColumnIndex == 0)
            a.ThrowException = false;
    };
    dataGridView1.CellFormatting += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (a.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            a.Value = dataGridView1[a.ColumnIndex, a.RowIndex].Value;
            a.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    };

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the `ColumnIndex` of the `column` in your code programmingly? Right now you are hard coded to 0 (`if (a.ColumnIndex == 0)`).

Comment: You know the column which you want to suppress its exceptions. So hardcoding the index of the column or name of the column is right. For name, you can say `dataGridView1.Columns[a.Index].Name == "C1"`. Also if you always want to suppress the exception, don't check for column index/name.

Comment: I just have I column has the issue so I use the if condition. I use `if (e.ColumnIndex == DGV.Columns[column.Name].Index)`.